# AC - On 8m, Off 10s

Tags: hvac

I recently had a new Goodman GSX130241 installed for my home's central air.  I noticed something odd (to me at least) -- when I set my thermostat (basic Honeywell, has worked fine all winter with the heat [gas, so not directly related to this AC unit]) to a low temp, like 68 degrees (in the 80s here), to basically hold/cool continuously, it seems to turn on/off frequently:

I recorded it over 2hrs today and found it approx. turns on for 8m and off for 10s, for the 2hr test (audio recorded it, now looking at the whole 2h recording as a simple graph). Is this normal behavior, when I set it to just keep running non-stop?

e: I've read the variety of reasons for a unit to go "on/off frequently", but I am wondering if this particular behavior rises to that level, or if this is expected... should it run more non-stop?

Comment: What is turning on/off? The A/C condenser unit outside? Or the interior blower that circulates air?  There's a difference.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't tack on keywords. Take the [tour] for tips.

Answer (score 1):

It would be not normal to cycle like that.

WITHOUT SCHEMATIC LETS DO SOME ROUGH DEBUGGING.

Bypass the thermostat to exclude it from been the problem maker.

Use piece of wire and bridge the R (on the thermostat) and the Y, that should give you constant cooling.

If you are low on coolant (leak) the low pressure sensor will turn off the compressor. Will need professional to check and fix.

Turn on the Fan-only mode to check the fan function.

It could be the drip pan overflow sensor. In the cabinet where is the fan is located, look at drip pan and unplug the water level sensor. Meanwhile check the water level in the pan (should be none).

Back to beginning. The only device that has a timer is the thermostat that could do the 8 minute on then off.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know, thanks. I guess I will ask the contractor who installed it about it further, if that's abnormal.  It's interesting that the cadence was so regular at about 8m/10s for most of the test.. I'll try it again tomorrow, maybe mess with the fan Auto or On.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the fan speed. If its high, then it will probably do more cycles.

And if the air is getting disturbed by people walking near the thermostat, then it might do more cycles.

My only other thought is that the unit is under-powered and can not cope with the size of the room.  In which case, it may have to recover, before carrying on.

Comment: The thermostat has a Fan [On] or [Auto] - for this test, I set it to On (and it seems to stay on with or without cooling, goes off if set to auto and cool/heat off).